# How to add text or label inside a shape?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm relatively new to programming (atleast with WPF). At the moment, I'm trying to create a diagram designer. I have take a look for this guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part .
I'm using the Part4 as a base for my own project.

Now I would like to have "name tags" or labels for the shapes(?) (Picture below). I already got the label to the shape, but the problems are:

- The same text will be in each and every shape. Instead of that, I want individual name for every shape.
- The text will only be shown, when the object is dragged and dropped to the canvas. It will not show in the list (StackPanel) on the left. [Here is a picture of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aag8f.jpg)

I know, that the text will be in every shape, because it is added in the "DesignerItem Style". That's because I could't make it work with any other way I tried.

**Here is some code from the project:**

Creating the shapes in FlowChartStencils.xaml :

```
<Brush x:Key="ItemStroke">Black</Brush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ItemBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" Opacity="1">
<LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
  <GradientStop Color="Lavender" Offset="0.01" />
  <GradientStop Color="Salmon" Offset="0.5" />
  <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>

</LinearGradientBrush>
  <Style x:Key="FlowChartItemStyle" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource ItemBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource ItemStroke}"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0.2"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeLineJoin" Value="Round"/>
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Process" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlowChartItemStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 0,0 V60 H50 V0 Z" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Process_DragThumb" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource Process}">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

Could I somehow add a label/textblock (or similar) straight to code shown above? Or is there a better way to create and edit such squares/rectangles?

The label I'm adding in DesignerItem.xaml :

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LabelDecoratorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Grid Margin="0,5,5,0">
        <Label x:Name="ItemLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="HELLO"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>


<!-- DesignerItem Style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type s:DesignerItem}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type s:DesignerItem}">
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      ContextMenu="{StaticResource DesignerItemContextMenu}">
                    ...
                    ...
                    <!-- PART_Label -->
                    <Control x:Name="PART_Label"
                             Visibility="Visible"
                             Template="{StaticResource LabelDecoratorTemplate}"
                             IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                             ...
                             ...
```

Is it possible to get the "Key" -property from each shape, in this case it would be "Process", so that could be used as a content to show as a label?

Apologies for possibly a bit confusing post. I will greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding or not visualizing correctly. When you say "get the Key property from each shape" what does that mean? I see you've got the Path's and then drop a label on them but I think I'm missing what exactly you're trying to grab to substitute them maybe? Neat project either way though.

Comment: Oh, I see that is not clearly said. What I mean, is: "get the Key property" --> in this case it would be "Process". That the key -property of the first rectangle/shape. I will update that to the original post aswell.

Comment: Seeing the rest of your XAML would likely help and I'm thinking I could show another way. From the bits that I can see, you could set a Setter for the `Tag` property of each shape with the name of each shape (aka the Key) and pass that into your control template the same way you're passing in your Path Data.

Comment: Do you mean I should set a Setter for `Tag` property right below the `Data` setter? And then pass the `Tag` property to control template with Key "LabelDecoratorTemplate"?

Comment: Just a quick `<Setter Property="Tag" Value="Whatever Name"/>` then I can only assume you're using the Data property as `{TemplateBinding Data}` so you would just do `{TemplateBinding Tag}`

Comment: Thanks, I see that would have done the job. I already changed the structure of the "FlowChartStencils.xaml" -file. It's now more like the "ShapeStencils.xaml" in the original project: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part). I addition, I added a `Grid` around the `Path`, and another `Grid` in parallel with `Path`. Inside that, I added the `Label`. Not a clean solution, but it does what I want.

Comment: As long as you found a decent remedy. :)